# SlashDB returns 502 on long URL

Tags: rest, slashdb

I'm using SlashDB to layer a REST interface over MySQL back-end. Mostly, I define queries through the 'SQL Pass-thru' feature. We're using this system to record test data from various test station.

When sending test data into the database, it seems SlashDB chokes once the URL exceeds a certain length (about 2K worth of data). The error returned was '502', which is strange because URI too long normally returns a '414'. When I try the query directly in MySQL, there was no problem.

Here's the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_result` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test_instance_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `test_instance_test_station_id` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `test_instance_unit_sn` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `test_instance_contact_address_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `testStep` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `testData` blob,
  `externalDataLink` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_test_result_test_instance1_idx` (`test_instance_id`,`test_instance_test_station_id`,`test_instance_unit_sn`,`test_instance_contact_address_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_test_result_test_instance1` FOREIGN KEY (`test_instance_id`, `test_instance_test_station_id`, `test_instance_unit_sn`, `test_instance_contact_address_id`) REFERENCES `test_instance` (`id`, `test_station_id`, `unit_sn`, `contact_address_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And here's the URL (with the big data truncated):

/post-test-result/testId/116/locationId/99/stationId/BO-01/sn/991807000003/stepName/test2/testData/[2K's worth of data here]/dataUrl/bye2.json?limit=29

The query defined through 'SQL Pass-thru':

insert into test_result (test_instance_id, test_instance_contact_address_id, test_instance_test_station_id, test_instance_unit_sn, testStep, testData, externalDataLink) values
(:testId, :locationId, :stationId, :sn, :stepName, :testData, :dataUrl);

Would anybody be able to shed any light?

Comment: Just to clarify, it is the value for the testData parameter that makes the URL long?

Comment: Correct! The testDats parameter makes the URL long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updaing uwsgi buffer values in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file

```
server {
    uwsgi_buffer_size 8k;
    uwsgi_buffers  4 8k;
    uwsgi_busy_buffers_size 16k;

# ... #
```

and `/etc/slashdb/slashdb.ini` file, at the end of section `[uwsgi]` add `buffer-size = 32768`. Section uwsgi should look like:

```
# uWSGI config for service scriptm starts uWSGI as a daemon
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:8001
virtualenv = /opt/slashdb
daemonize = /var/log/slashdb/uwsgi.log
log-maxsize = 20971520
master = true
enable-threads = true
single-interpreter = true
lazy-apps = true
processes = 1
threads = 2
paste = config:%p
paste-logger = %p
buffer-size = 32768
```

Then restart services:

```
sudo service slashdb stop
sudo service slashdb start
sudo service nginx restart
```

BTW SlashDB at the moment does not reflect BLOB type but if you changed `testData` column type to `text` then you would be able to use POST method in Data Discovery which seams more suitable for your use case.

Using curl it would be

```
curl -v 'http://slashdb.reshareu/db/testing/test_result.json' \
-X POST \
-H 'apikey: your-api-key-here' \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "test_instance_test_station_id": "BO-01",
  "test_instance_contact_address_id": 99,
  "test_instance_unit_sn": "991807000003",
  "testStep": "test2",
  "externalDataLink": "bye2",
  "test_instance_id": 116,
  "testData": "Very long yata, yata, yata..."
}'
```

Comment: The uwsgi buffer values don't work, unfortunately. However, I notice something strange as well. On my SlashDB installation, uwsgi doesn't run. 

$ sudo systemctl status uwsgi
● uwsgi.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: I've reproduced your error in my env. End uwsgi_buffer size worked for url around 3k characters long. Have you reloaded nginx after making changes? 
To see if SlashDB is running try `ps uax | grep uwsgi` and see if the process is running. 
BTW, how did you install SlashDB script, system package, docker? Which version of SlashDB are you using?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me with this.

I installed SlashDB as a system package, as prescribed on the website. It's version 0.9.53.

Yes, I restarted SlashDB and memcached after I changed the configuration file. I even tried rebooting the virtual machine. `ps uax | grep uwsgi` came up empty even when SlashDB was running and responding. This issue crops up on all my development machine, by the way (I have 2).

Comment: OK, I forgot to write about change in uwsgi settings in /etc/slashdb/slashdb.ini. I've updated my answer.

Comment: If `ps aux | grep uwsgi` doesn't return anything then SlashDB isn't running. When visiting main page you should be getting `502 Bad Gateway`. Unless you've setup caching then responses could be coming from nginx cache.` Also take a look of nginx logs, they're in  `/var/log/nginx` to what's actual reason for 502 error.

Comment: mdob, your latest update to slashdb.ini works! The curl for the 'Data Discovery' mode works as well. Now, we have a couple of ways to do this.

Further clarification:
1. How does the buffer-size in slashdb.ini relate to the uwsgi_buffer_size in nginx.conf?
2. Is this information in the SlashDB documentation? I'd like to learn more.
3. Is it possible to put data in the body of a request (as in your curl example), but through SlashDB's SQL Pass-thru feature?

Thanks a bunch for the help!

Comment: @AntoniusGan In general nginx which works as reverse proxy and uwsgi as application server. Both limit header size to something around 4-8KB, perhaps to maintain stability or prevent http header injection or simply to save memory. It's very unusual to use very long urls (over 2000 characetrs). Have a look at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_buffer_size about and https://uwsgi-docs-additions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#buffer-size